# For $a,b$ in abelian group $G$ of orders $m,n$ where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, $|ab| = mn$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove this following result.

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $a,b$ be elements with orders $m,n$, respectively, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Prove that $|ab| = mn$.

Here is my attempt. There is one final step that I cannot figure out.

> Let $G$ be an abelian group with identity $e$, and let $a,b \in G$ with the property that $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. We have:
> \begin{align*}
> (ab)^{mn} & = a^{mn} b^{mn} & & \text{since $G$ is abelian} \\
> & = (a^n)^m (b^m)^n \\
> & = e^m e^n \\
> & = ee \\
> & = e
> \end{align*}
> Define $t := |ab|$. I claim that $t \mid mn$. By the division algorithm, there exist unique $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r$ with the property that $0 \leq r < t$ such that
> $$mn = kt + r.$$
> We therefore have
> \begin{align*}
> (ab)^{mn} & = (ab)^{kt + r} \\
> & = (ab)^{kt} (ab)^r \\
> & = ((ab)^t)^k (ab)^r \\
> & = e^k (ab)^r \\
> & = e(ab)^r \\
> & = (ab)^r
> \end{align*}
> Since $(ab)^{mn} = e$, and $(ab)^{mn} = (ab)^r$, we deduce $(ab)^r = e$ by transitivity of equality. But, $r$ is non-negative by definition and is strictly less than $t$, the order of $ab$. If $r$ is positive, this contradicts the definition of order, so we must have $r = 0$. Hence, $mn = kt$. That is, $t \mid mn$, or $|ab| \mid mn$.

> Now, since $t$ is the order of $ab$, we have
> $$(ab)^t = a^t b^t = e,$$
> but we have
> $$e = e^n = (a^t b^t)^n = (a^t)^n (b^t)^n = a^{tn} b^{tn} = a^{tn} (b^n)^t = a^{tn} e^t = a^{tn} e = a^{tn}.$$
> Since $a^{tn} = e$, by the earlier result, the order of $a$ divides the $tn$. That is, $m \mid tn$. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $m \mid t$. By an exactly analogous argument, we deduce $n \mid t$. Indeed,
> $$e = e^m = (a^t b^t)^m = (a^m)^t b^{tm} = e^t b^{tm} = eb^{tm} = b^{tm},$$
> which again implies that the order of $b$ divides $tm$, that is, $n \mid tm$, and since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $n \mid t$.

The solution I am looking at goes one step further and argues that $n \mid t$ and $m \mid t$, so $mn \mid t$. I cannot figure out why this is the case. If in fact it were the case, the proof would be done since we earlier found that $t \mid mn$, so together with this fact, we'd have $t = mn$.

Comment: It is necessary to have $(n,m)=1$, in the general case we have $|ab|=gcm(m,n)$. Take the decomposition in prime factors.

Comment: @Tuvasbien It's not true in general that $|ab| = \mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$. For instance, if $m=n$ then $|ab|$ could be any divisor of $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(ab)^{|a| |b|}=a^{|a||b|}b^{|a||b|}=1$$
Therefore, $|ab|$ divides $|a||b|$. Conversely,
$$1=(ab)^{|ab|}=a^{|ab|}b^{|ab|}$$

implies that
$$1=1^{|b|}=a^{|b||ab|}b^{|b||ab|}=a^{|b||ab|}$$
Therefore, $|a|$ divides $|b||ab|$. Since $|a|$ and $|b|$ are coprime, you may write
$$1=|a|x+|b|y$$
for suitable integers $x$ and $y$. Then
$$|ab|=|a||ab|x+|b||ab|y$$
Since $|a|$ divides the right-hand-side, it also must divide $|ab|$. With a similar argument, you get that also $|b|$ divides $|ab|$. Hence $|a||b|=\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ divides $|ab|$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler approach:

- $(ab)^{mn}=e$
- $(ab)^{k}=e \implies k > mn$

You have already done the first part.

For the second part:
$
(ab)^{k}=e \implies a^k = b^{-k} \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{ e\}
$ because $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Can you finish now?